# Nested query on ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index which is storing documents in the following way:

```
    { 

  categorisedTags: 
   { urlTags: { L: [] },
     commodityTags: { L: [Array] },
     tags: { L: [] } },
  newOptions: [],
  created_at: 'Mon, 07 Oct 2019 12:55:34 GMT',
  name: 'Template ',
  }
```

I need to query the index by 'commodityTags', so given a string, it should return all documents where the string is included in the commodityTags array.

I have tried with:

```
service.queryTags = async (index, values) => {
    const { hits } = await esClient.search({
      index,
      type: '_doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          term: {
            'categorisedTags.commodityTags': 'oil'
          }
        },
      },
    });
    return hits.hits.map(({ _source }) => _source);
  };
```

But no luck, always returns 0 hits. How can I do this kind of nested queries on ES ?

Answer (score 1):

[Nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) can be created like below
Query

```
"query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "categorisedTags",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "term": {
               "categorisedTags.commodityTags": {
                 "value": "oil"
               }
             }
           }
         ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
```